# How to render html on a given view brefore RenderBody() from the layout is triggered

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm working on an `ASP.NET MVC3` project. I'm using `Twitter Bootstrap` for my styling (not sure if that's important). The problem I have is that my `Index.cshtml` view of the `Home` controller has slightly different layout from the other pages (additional image navigation at the top which I don't show once the user select where he wants to go) but this is causing problems so I remove this part from the `Index` view to another partial view `_ImageNavigation.cshtml` and what I want to do is render the content of this partial view when `Home/Index.cshtml` is opened and I want to render it before the `@RenderBody()` also independently from it so I get the page the way I want it.

Right now in my `_Layout.cshtml` I have:

```
 <div id="main">

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">@RenderBody() </div>
            <div class="col-md-2"> 
            //some static content
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

So I have two ideas first - adding `@RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_ImageNavigation.cshtml")` right before `@RenderBody()` like :

```
<div class="row">
@RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_ImageNavigation.cshtml")
<div class="col-md-10">@RenderBody() </div>
```

which produces the effect I want, but as you may guess `_ImageNavigation` is rendered on every page which is not what I want. I want it only on my `Home/Index.cshtml` so I guess the maybe some kind of check could be made to see what view is loading and render `_ImageNavigation` only if it's the correct view. Something like :

```
if (LoadingView == Home/Index.cshtml)
  {
    @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_ImageNavigation.cshtml")
  }
```

Of course the above is just pseudo code, I don't know if it's possible and how to make such a check. And also I wonder if there is a way to do it in the page itself. I tried to put `@RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_ImageNavigation.cshtml")` directly in my `Home/Index.cshtml` but obviously this way the page is rendered as if the code is written directly in the View and not loaded explicitly.

Maybe there's other way. This seems like pretty standard problem but I don't seem to find a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a smaller number of exceptions I like to use Sections.  Here is a very simlified example:

Layout:

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("Nav")) 
{
  RenderSection("Nav")
}
else 
{ 
  <nav>default nav</nav>
}
@RenderBody()
```

Page with alternative nav:

```
@section Nav
{
  <nav>My alternate nav</nav>
}

<div>This is the body for RenderBody</div>
```

You can read more on [Defining Default Content For A Razor Layout Section - Phil Haacked](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/05/defining-default-content-for-a-razor-layout-section.aspx/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I slowed my comment because I had problem with : `@if (IsSectionDefined("Nav"))` with it I got this error : `The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page`. Leaving only `RenderSection("Nav")` solved this problem though. I was expecting errors when opening other pages but it works fine. I wonder what's causing this, but it seems that I'm not obligated to define the section in each view to use only `RenderSection("Nav")`.

Comment: You may want to use `RenderSection("Nav", false)`.

Comment: Yep, not sure why, I saw many examples suggesting using `IsSectionDefined()` but in my case just `RenderSection("Nav", false)` is the option that doesn't cause the yellow screen of dead. Thanks for help.

Comment: `IsSectionDefinied()` would allow you to have a default value.  Without it, ie the section is not defined, nothing is rendered.